# Give input radio attribute checked

Tags: jquery

I try to give the radio input checked if the radio input has the value.
The code below give no result.

HTML MARKUP

```
<input type="radio" class="catradio" id="cattype_one" name="cattype" value="1"/>
<input type="radio" class="catradio" id="cattype_two" name="cattype" value="2"/>
```

jQuery MARKUP

```
$(".catradio").filter('value="1"').prop('checked', true);
```

Who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.filter()` does not recognise `"value='1'"` as valid and throws an error.

Try this instead:

```js
$(":radio[value=1]").prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" class="catradio" id="cattype_one" name="cattype" value="1"/>
<input type="radio" class="catradio" id="cattype_two" name="cattype" value="2"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't set the `checked` on the html itself, then use `$(".catradio[value=1]").prop('checked', true);`

**Demo**

```js
$(".catradio[value=1]").prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" class="catradio" id="cattype_one" name="cattype" value="1"/>
<input type="radio" class="catradio" id="cattype_two" name="cattype" value="2"/>
```

Comment: @Shree ;) hehe  Next time you might beat me :P

Answer (score 0):

With HTML u can use `checked`:

```
<input type="radio" name="cattype" value="2" checked/>
```

No need for jQuery.